# Directive and Controller don't together, I get InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5 setAttribute@[native code]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a universal navigation bar that I have as a directive:

```
  angular.module("mainPageApp", [])
  .directive("navbar", function() { 
  return {
    restrict: "E",         
    replace: true,         
    transclude: true,      
    templateUrl: "angular/directives/bootstrapNavbar.html",    
    compile: function(element, attrs) {  
      var li, liElements, links, index, length;

      liElements = $(element).find("#navigation-tabs li");   
      for (index = 0, length = liElements.length; index < length; index++) {
        li = liElements[index];
        links = $(li).find("a");  
        if (links[0].textContent === attrs.currentTab) $(li).addClass("active"); 
      }
    }
  }});
 ;
```

And this directive works. I have tried it, and it load everything just fine. Then I have this controller:

```
var mainPageApp = angular.module('mainPageApp', []);

mainPageApp.controller('bioController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('json/bio.json').success(function(bios){
        //Bio info
        $scope.fields = bios;
    })
    $http.get('json/socialLinks.json').success(function(links){
        //Social links
        $scope.socialLinks = links;
    })
});
```

This too works fine, but on its own. If I put the two together in my index.html, I get the following error:

```
[Error] Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5
setAttribute@[native code]
attr@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:147:149
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:149:52
$set@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:65:359
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:58:409
r@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:7:396
D@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:58:319
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:60:84
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:72:46
K@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:100:79
K@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:100:79
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:101:246
$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:15
$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:109:101
$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:352
h@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:72:306
x@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:77:446
onreadystatechange@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:78:376
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 92)
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 68)
    K (angular.min.js, line 100)
    K (angular.min.js, line 100)
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 101)
    $eval (angular.min.js, line 112)
    $digest (angular.min.js, line 109)
    $apply (angular.min.js, line 112)
    h (angular.min.js, line 72)
    x (angular.min.js, line 77)
    onreadystatechange (angular.min.js, line 78)
```

And so, I am wondering what it is I am doing wrong. I think it is a scoping issue, but still I am a little rusty (haven't worked in angular in about 6 months).

Comment: I think you are creating two module with name **mainPageApp** since `angular.module('mainPageApp', [])` creates a new module while `angular.module('mainPageApp')` uses an existing module.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks!